# Issue with Sonarqube connection with Sonarlint in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I am trying to work in connected mode in between Sonarlint extension in Visual Studio 2022 and Sonarqube using Token, I get the following error :

ERROR: Could not find compatible implementation of 'IGetExclusionsRequest' for SonarQube 6.7.0.33306.
SonarQube request failed: Could not find compatible implementation of 'IGetExclusionsRequest' for SonarQube 6.7.0.33306.
Unexpected error during workflow execution: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: serverExclusions.

SonarLint version
[7.0.0.74072](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQj35.png)

Sonarqube version : Version 6.7 (build 33306)

I am expecting sonarqube and sonarlint in my local visual studio should work in connected mode.

Comment: Your SonarQube version is pretty old, SonarLint only supports the oldest LTS which is currently 7.9 as of today.